# Conditional Binding: if let error – Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type

Tags: ios, swift, optional-binding

I am trying to delete a row from my Data Source and the following line of code:

```
if let tv = tableView {
```

causes the following error:

> Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not
>   UITableView

Here is the full code:

```
// Override to support editing the table view.
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle:UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    if editingStyle == .Delete {

        // Delete the row from the data source

    if let tv = tableView {

            myData.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row)

            tv.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
```

How should I correct the following?

```
 if let tv = tableView {
```

Comment: since `tableView` is not an optional value, there is no need to check whether it is nil or not. So you can directly use it, I mean remove that `if let`  and just use `tableView` in the function

Comment: For posterity, after I fixed this issue, I ran into `variable with getter/setter cannot have an initial value`, which was resolved by simply removing the leftover { } block after the initialization, ala this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/36002958/4544328

Answer (score 260, accepted):

`if let`/`if var` optional binding only works when the result of the right side of the expression is an optional.  If the result of the right side is not an optional, you can not use this optional binding.  The point of this optional binding is to check for `nil` and only use the variable if it's non-`nil`.

In your case, the `tableView` parameter is declared as the non-optional type `UITableView`.  It is guaranteed to never be `nil`.  So optional binding here is unnecessary.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle:UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    if editingStyle == .Delete {
        // Delete the row from the data source
        myData.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row)
        tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
```

All we have to do is get rid of the `if let` and change any occurrences of `tv` within it to just `tableView`.

Answer (score 26):

for my specific problem I had to replace

```
if let count = 1
    {
        // do something ...
    }
```

With

```
let count = 1
if(count > 0)
    {
        // do something ...
    }
```

Comment: Best answer by this guy see the comments https://stackoverflow.com/a/31039427/2797944

Answer (score 21):

In a case where you are using a custom cell type, say ArticleCell, you might get an error that says :

```
    Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not 'ArticleCell'
```

You will get this error if your line of code looks something like this:

```
    if let cell = tableView.dequeReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ArticleCell",for indexPath: indexPath) as! ArticleCell
```

You can fix this error by doing the following :

```
    if let cell = tableView.dequeReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ArticleCell",for indexPath: indexPath) as ArticleCell?
```

If you check the above, you will see that the latter is using optional casting for a cell of type ArticleCell.

Comment: In my case I needed to use `as! ArticleCell?`

Answer (score 12):

Same applies for **guard** statements. The same error message lead me to this post and answer (thanks @nhgrif).

The code: Print the last name of the person only if the middle name is less than four characters.

```
func greetByMiddleName(name: (first: String, middle: String?, last: String?)) {
    guard let Name = name.last where name.middle?.characters.count < 4 else {
        print("Hi there)")
        return
    }
    print("Hey \(Name)!")
}
```

Until I declared **last** as an optional parameter I was seeing the same error.

Answer (score 5):

condition binding must have optinal type which mean that you can only bind optional values in if let statement

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    if editingStyle == .delete {

        // Delete the row from the data source

        if let tv = tableView as UITableView? {


        }
    }
}
```

This will work fine but make sure when you use if let it must have optinal type "?"

Answer (score 3):

Well, it'd still be convenient (syntactically) if we could declare usual values inside the if's condition. So, here's a trick: you can make the compiler think there is an assignment of `Optional.some(T)` to a value like so:

```swift
    if let i = "abc".firstIndex(of: "a"),
        let i_int = .some(i.utf16Offset(in: "abc")),
        i_int < 1 {
        // Code
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

What it is telling you is - the `2nd guard let` or the `if let check` is not happening on an Optional Int or Optional String. You already have a non-optional value, so guarding or if-letting is not needed anymore

Answer (score -1):

if you check for textfield make sure optional text?

```
  guard let msg = message.text?.trimmed,!messaged.isEmpty,messaged.count >= 14 else {
            MyVariables.status.image = UIImage(named: "wrong")
            MyVariables.status.message = "Enter Your Message".localized
            MyVariables.status.showInKeyWindow()
            return
        }
```

Comment: if let dishes = allDishes.categories{
                                ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators: false) {
                                    LazyHStack {
                                        ForEach(dishes) { dish in
                                            CategoryView(dish: dish)
                                        }
                                    }
                                }.frame(height: 128)
                            } same error I got