# Swift to swift 2 guard let

Tags: swift

```
let renderEncoderOpt = commandBuffer.renderCommandEncoderWithDescriptor(renderPassDescriptor)

if let renderEncoder = renderEncoderOpt {
  renderEncoder.setRenderPipelineState(pipelineState)
  renderEncoder.setVertexBuffer(vertexBuffer, offset: 0, atIndex: 0)
  renderEncoder.drawPrimitives(.Triangle, vertexStart: 0, vertexCount: 3, instanceCount: 1)
  renderEncoder.endEncoding()
}
```

The code above throws an

```
 Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not 'MTLRenderCommandEncoder'
```

If i try and make renderEncoderOpt an optional though, the issue still remains. I've tried testing with guard let vs if let, and tried setting it to optionals, and redeclaring type etc, but it keeps coming back to this issue. This worked ok in swift 1/1.2

Does anyone have an pointers?

Comment: I would suspect that the right hand side of top line (= commandBuffer...) is not an optional. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31038759/if-let-error-initializer-for-conditional-binding-must-have-optional-type-not

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `renderCommandEncoderWithDescriptor` is not returning an optional, so you should remove the `if let` conditional binding altogether and just use result directly.

```
let renderEncoder = commandBuffer.renderCommandEncoderWithDescriptor(renderPassDescriptor)

renderEncoder.setRenderPipelineState(pipelineState)
renderEncoder.setVertexBuffer(vertexBuffer, offset: 0, atIndex: 0)
renderEncoder.drawPrimitives(.Triangle, vertexStart: 0, vertexCount: 3, instanceCount: 1)
renderEncoder.endEncoding()
```

Comment: Thanks for this! I actually figured it out in the end, but this is how i did it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Rob answered this question in the comments. You can't use the `if let` syntax if the object isn't optional. This error is telling you that.

Answer (score 0):

The function renderCommandEncoderWithDescriptor is defined as follows

```
func renderCommandEncoderWithDescriptor(_ renderPassDescriptor: MTLRenderPassDescriptor) -> MTLRenderCommandEncoder
```

(source: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Metal/Reference/MTLCommandBuffer_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/MTLCommandBuffer/renderCommandEncoderWithDescriptor:)

The return type MTLRenderCommandEncoder is a graphics rendering command encoder object, which is a non-optional object. 
(source: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Metal/Reference/MTLRenderCommandEncoder_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/swift/intf/c:objc(pl)MTLRenderCommandEncoder)

Hence, your if let conditional binding

```
if let renderEncoder = renderEncoderOpt {
```

fails. Simply remove this if statement and your code should work.