# I get error on my Xcode7.

Tags: swift, xcode7

The error is "Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not 'UITabBarItem'"

```
     lass BaseTabBarViewController: UITabBarController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    //The code below is the reason I get error for
     if let notif = (self.tabBar.items?[2])! as UITabBarItem {
        NotificationManager.sharedInstance.notifTabbar = notif
    }else{
        //            NotificationManager.sharedInstance.notifTabbar.badgeValue = ""
    }
```

Comment: The error answers itself. Read it again and ponder

Comment: Possible duplicate of [If Let Error - Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not 'UITableView'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31038759/if-let-error-initializer-for-conditional-binding-must-have-optional-type-not)

Answer (score 1):

anytime you're doing an `if let` you want the initializer to be an optional

for example

```
if let hello = world as? String {
    // do blah
}
```

a quick easy way to know whether your if let ______ is an optional is to click on the world and look at your right panel and click on the **?** icon.