# Error: Variable with getter/setter cannot have an initial value

Tags: swift, initialization, setter, getter

How do I fix this error?

> Variable with getter/setter cannot have an initial value

Here's my code:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
  var cell: UITableViewCell = tableview.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as UITableViewCell {     //Error
    cell.textLabel?.text = self.items[indexPath.row] //Error
    return cell;  //Error
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I think you have an extra set of `{}`  As it is, you're defining a block and assigning it to the cell variable:

```
var cell: UITableViewCell = tableview.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as UITableViewCell
cell.textLabel?.text = self.items[indexPath.row] //Error
return cell;  //Error
```

And, since `dequeueReusableCell...` returns a UITableViewCell already, all you really need is:

```
var cell = tableview.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell")
```

My guess is you cut/copied code that started out looking like:

```
if let cell = tableview.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as? MyCellClass {
    // some setup code here
    return cell
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much that is exactly what i needed

Comment: @SonnySluiter don't forget to mark this answer as correct. This was my issue as well. Started with an `if let` that had the block, got the if let condition must be an Optional type error, removed that and ended up with this error. Removing the block is what fixed it, and I think a lot of people may come across this issue as well after fixing the same one I did.