# Error "Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not 'String'" trying to sort column in Swift 5, NSTableView

Tags: swift, xcode, swift5

I'm receiving error `Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not 'String'`on line:

```
guard let id1 = p1.artist, let id2 = p2.artist else { return true }
```

Any advice on how to kill this error?  THANK YOU!

```
func setSortDescriptor() {
    let idDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "cellArtist", ascending: true)
    tableView.tableColumns[0].sortDescriptorPrototype = idDescriptor
}


func tableView(_ tableView: NSTableView, sortDescriptorsDidChange oldDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor]) {
    guard let sortDescriptor = tableView.sortDescriptors.first else { return }
    sortRecords(ascending: sortDescriptor.ascending)
    tableView.reloadData()
}

func sortRecords(ascending: Bool) {
    myRecords.sort { (p1, p2) -> Bool in
        guard let id1 = p1.artist, let id2 = p2.artist else { return true }
        if ascending {
            return id1 < id2
        } else {
            return id2 < id1
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of: [Conditional Binding: if let error – Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31038759/conditional-binding-if-let-error-initializer-for-conditional-binding-must-hav)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not showing the type of `p1` or `p2`, but on at least one (probably both if they're the same type), the property `artist` is defined as a `String`. In order to use `guard let` or `if let`, the variable/property you're binding to must be an Optional (`String?`, for example).

If these are both non-optional `String`s, there's no reason to do the `guard` statement, since there's nothing to bind -- you can just do your comparisons directly on `p1.artist` and `p2.artist`.

More reading on optional bindings: https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/TheBasics.html

Comment: Thank you. That did it.  I did not need the guard at all!!! :)

Comment: @DouglasBrown did you check the link I sent you yesterday?

Comment: @LeoDabus yes. I got it working. now I was trying to make a column clickable :) I have it working ;)   but my next problem is I need to figure out the index of the column that is clicked. lol one after another. Any idea on that one Leo?   I hope you are well!   Thanks for all your help. You helped big time yesterday... just moving through my goals lol

Comment: @LeoDabus if I can get the index of the column that is clicked I change change the 'tableView.tableColumns[0].sortDescriptorPrototype = idDescriptor' line to that index vs. 0 and then I can make all the column work. right now I have one sortable. but I hav 4 to go ;) lol FUN :)

Comment: @LeoDabus I responded to the other question thread that you replied to last night with the code example download.  THANK YOU BTW!